# Problem with Functions which has default parameter(s)

Tags: python, function, default-parameters

I have some question about functions which have default parameters.

```
import sys
from random import randint

my_list = [1,2,3]
def Veli(a, b = my_list):
    my_list.append(randint(1,1500))
    print a + b[-1]

print "Number of Refs:", sys.getrefcount(my_list)
print "Def args:", Veli.func_defaults
Veli(1) # This is 4
Veli(1) # We almost always obtain different result because of randint
Veli(1) # Again different results.
print Veli.func_defaults
print "Number of Refs:", sys.getrefcount(my_list)
Veli(1)
my_list = [-5] # old my_list has different address 
print "Number of Refs:", sys.getrefcount(my_list) # Less than previous
print "Def args:", Veli.func_defaults
Veli(1) # Now gives same results.
print "Def args:", Veli.func_defaults
Veli(1) # Same result again...
```

Outputs: (Some numbers depend on which values randint has returned, of course.)

> 

Number of Refs: 3
  Def args: ([1, 2, 3],)
  322
  1119
  740
  ([1, 2, 3, 321, 1118, 739],)
  Number of Refs: 3
  303
  Number of Refs: 2
  Def args: ([1, 2, 3, 321, 1118, 739, 302],)
  303
  Def args: ([1, 2, 3, 321, 1118, 739, 302],)
  303

The following code gives you a number less than the previous one, because b and my_list is not referenced to same address anymore.

```
print "#ref:", sys.getrefcount(my_list) # Less than previous
```

Now, we have a way (the only way?) to reach b, default argument of the function:

```
Veli.func_defaults[0]
```

Sorry about my long explanation. Here is my questions:

1. Is this a problem? Dictionary of my module crush my_list variable then now my_list variable has default address than previous. Then function which uses global variable named my_list in its body is changing (growing) while my default argument is not. Why cannot `b` see global variable named `my_list` when `a + b[-1]` expression is executed? I know, `b` has different address with my_list (because [mutual objects (like list) are guaranteed to refer to different, unique, newly created list](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)) now, but why were Python implemented so that `b` cannot see the global variables when b is a function arguments? Could you explain comprehensively?
2. Is there any way to get same results with Veli.func_defaults[0]? This code executed then let say, I want to change my default arguments of my function named Veli. I cannot do this with my_list, because my_list and b have different addresses. One way is changing the elements of the list, Veli.func_defaults[0]. Is there any different way(s)?
3. (It is not so related to code above) How can get addresses of variable? For example, how can get address of `b`? I use built-in function such as `__hash__` , but there should be more appropriate way.

Notes:

a) This codes may be useless for any reason, but I want to learn opinions.
b) Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39)
 [GCC 4.4.5] on linux2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @ncoghlan: Upvoted as it's important lecture, but since OP exploits this behaviour, not completely relevant here.

Comment: Oops, I actually thought I deleted that after rereading the OP's question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Defaults arguments are bounds at function definition time. The line `def Veli(a, b = my_list):` puts a reference to the object `my_list` happens to refer to *at that time* into `func_defaults`. Python *never* uses pass-by-reference - variables hold references and those references are always passed by value. So what's actually saved in `b`, a reference (pointer), is copied and nobody remembers where it came from or bothers to update it.
2. <del>Not quite sure what you're asking, please clarify. `b` will be `Veli.func_defaults[0]` if no second argument was passed, but obviously different if it is passed (well, unless of course the caller accesses `func_defaults`... you should assume he doesn't).</del>You could, as suggested in another answer, make `b`default to `None` and use the global `my_list` if `b is None` - this would give you a fresh, updated copy of its reference on every call. Perhaps you should write a class and keep the default value as an attribute of `self` and apply the usual `(... = None): if ... is None: use = default` idiom.
3. The build-in function `id`. Actually, it's implementation defined what this returns (doesn't have to be the address), as long as it's an integer that represents the object identity, i.e. distinct objects (with overlapping lifetimes) have a distinct `id` and the same object always gives the same `id` during its lifetime. The easy return value, which CPython chooses, is the address.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument), as your question is essentially related to the same problem (albeit with a slightly different perspective on the topic).

As you note, when the function *definition* is executed, `b` is bound to point to `my_list`. When you later change `my_list` to point to a different object, `b` remains unaffected.

To get "lazy binding" you want to write your function like this:

```
def Veli(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = my_list # Gets value of my_list at call time
    my_list.append(randint(1,1500))
    print a + b[-1]
```

Comment: your explanation is more clear than delnan but you answered only one question and also delnan is the first answerer. I picked him/her. Thank you for your answer